# Spreadsheet Manipulations in Single Procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I have written VBA code to copy and do some formatting and create sheets based on unique reference and insert some information. I want to optimize this code and make it short as much I can. The code is broken into parts to help make clearer what I am doing with it.

```
 Sub Previous_comments_and_modifications()

Dim x As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ds As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim updatesheet As String
Dim main_book As String
Dim user As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
user = Environ("username")
main_book = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Inserting formulas on sheet SAP Data

lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data")
    .Range("B1").Value = "Assignment"
    .Range("Q1").Value = "CC + GL"
    .Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Formula = "=RC[-13]&""-""&RC[-11]"
    .Range("R1").Value = "No. of Days"
    .Range("S1").Value = "Ageing Group"
    .Range("T1").Value = "Posting Done By"

    With Sheets("Sap Data").Activate
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Columns(18).NumberFormat = "0"
        Range("R2").Formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)-N2"
        Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & lastRow)
    End With

    With Sheets("Sap Data").Activate
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B2").Formula = "=Get_LongDescription(RC[1])"
        Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    End With

    With Sheets("Sap Data").Activate
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]<=30,""0 - 30 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=60,""31 - 60 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=90,""61 - 90 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=120,""91 - 120 Days"",""121+ Days""))))"
        Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
    End With

    With Sheets("Sap Data").Activate
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("T2").Formula = "=IF((OR(G2=A2,G2=""WEB_ICWF"")),VLOOKUP(D2,'Automated BL Import'!$N:$Q,4,1),G2)"
        Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
    End With

    'Sorting Data on basis of column Q so it can be used to create new sheets
    With .Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Q2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range("A2:U" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With

'On basis of Column Q Data it is creating new sheets with Unique values
For Each a In Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data").Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow)
    If a.Value <> a.Offset(-1).Value Then
        With Workbooks(main_book)
        .Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        .Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = a.Value
        .Sheets(a.Value).Rows(1) = Sheets("Sap Data").Rows(1).Value
        End With
    End If
    x = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(a.Value).Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(a.Value).Rows(x) = a.EntireRow.Value
Next a

Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data").Range("Q:T").Delete

'In new created sheets it is inserting new Columns and required fields
For Each ws In Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sap Data" And ws.Name <> "Automated BL Import" Then
        With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name)
        .Range("T1").Value = "Posting Done By"
        .Range("U1").Value = "Class"
        .Range("V1").Value = "When it will be Cleared"
        .Range("W1").Value = "Action Taken/Required"
        .Range("X1").Value = "Backup Link"
        lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow).Delete
        End With
    End If
Next ws

'Its asking to copying comments from Previous Month File

 b = MsgBox("Do you want to update comments for current postings from previous month?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Note:- If are runing this macro for the 1st time plese choose option 'No'", _
    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question")
If b = vbYes Then
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Please select previous month BL comment file to update comments.", , False)
    If Filename <> "False" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename, Format:=2
    End If
    updatesheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    For Each ws In Workbooks(main_book).Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sap Data" And ws.Name <> "Automated BL Import" Then
            For Each ds In Workbooks(updatesheet).Sheets
                If ds.Name = ws.Name Then
                    lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    'Some formulas are insterted to reduce manual calculation
                        With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name)
                        .Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-1]:R1048576C,2,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-1]:R1048576C,2,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("U2:U" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-2]:R1048576C,3,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-2]:R1048576C,3,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("V2:V" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-3]:R1048576C,4,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-3]:R1048576C,4,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("W2:W" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-4]:R1048576C,5,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-4]:R1048576C,5,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("X2:X" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-5]:R1048576C,6,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-5]:R1048576C,6,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("T2:X" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("T2:X" & lastRow).Value
                        End With
                    GoTo next_ws
                End If
            Next ds
next_ws:
        End If
    Next ws
    Windows(updatesheet).Close
End If

'Each sheet is subtotaling details on basis of Category of Column B
lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A2:W" & lastRow)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

startRow = 2
For Each C In Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B3:B" & lastRow + 1)
    If C <> C.Offset(-1) Then
        endRow = C.Offset(-1).Row
        With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C" & startRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("A" & startRow, "W" & endRow)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        startRow = C.Row
    End If
Next C

lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For x = lastRow To 3 Step -1
    If Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(x, "B").Offset(-1, 0).Value <> Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(x, "B").Value Then
        Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(x, "B").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next x
lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Coloring the sheet
With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name)
    .Range("A1:W1").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    .Range("A2:R" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 216, 216)
    .Range("S2:W" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 247, 205)
End With
startRow = Range("K2").Row
lastRow = Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each C In Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
    If C.Value = "" Then
        endRow = C.Offset(-1).Row
        C.Formula = "=SUM(K" & startRow & ":K" & endRow & ")"
        C.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Total"
        Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A" & C.Row, "W" & C.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(149, 179, 215)
        startRow = C.Offset(1).Row
    End If
Next C
Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets(ws.Name).Columns("A:W").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Autosaving the file with date in Documents
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = Date
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "BL Comment File on  " & Format(CStr(Now), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat _
:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd start by defining all of your variables and then using those variables (for instance the SAP DATA sheet can be a ws variable.

Comment: Please tell where i should and what i should i insert or replace as i am not oo good with codes... and thanks for reviewing..

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) is a good place to start

Comment: @Raystafarian  Ok. i understood I will edit and updat code. Any Other recommendations like Autofill or Cltrl +D in single code line as compare to multiple.

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Mast They asked me to update the code so they can review better. If u want i can remove acceptance from answer

Comment: No, update the code and make it a new question. Just don't touch the code in this question. It's all explained in the link.

Comment: @Mast... Ok no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first:

**`OPTION EXPLICIT`**
Before you do anything else, open the VBE, go to Tools --> Options --> and check "Require Variable Declaration". There is **never** a good reason to omit `Option Explicit` from the top of a module and that setting will automatically add it in for you.

Also, `dtDate` is declared and set but never used.

---

### Readabiltiy

Software development is roughly 80% **reading** code, and only 20% writing it. Especially when you're not writing from scratch, a lot of time is spent just understanding what a particular piece of code is doing and why.

---

**Meaningful Variable Names**

What on earth is `ds`? if I see that variable in the middle of a code block, I'm going to have absolutely no idea what it is or what it's doing. `ws` isn't quite as bad (I can at least assume it's a worksheet object), but how am I supposed to know which worksheet it's referring to?

In this case, you only use them to loop through the sheets in 2 distinct workbooks. So, I would suggest something like `ws_Source` and `ws_Destination`.

`updatesheet` and `main_book` are also problematic. If I see a variable called `main_book` I'm going to assume it's a workbook object. `updatesheet` could easily be a worksheet, a function/sub etc. `nameOfUpdateSheet` and `mainWbName` would be much better because they're **descriptive**, **concise** and **unambiguous**. See also `user` --> `userName`.

Later on, you use `a` as an **undeclared** holder for range objects. Don't do this. Ever. Declare your variables, and make them sound like what they are. Additionally, it is a universal convention that single-letter variables represent general counters e.g. `for x = 1 to 100` which only adds to the confusion your code creates.

---

**Naming Conventions**

Naming conventions are useful because they provide a common framework for people to 'parse' your code. In VBA, common conventions you should be aware of:

Procedure-level variables are written in `camelCase` (No spaces, all words capitalised except the first).

```
dim localVariable as variant
```

Module and Global-level variables are written in `PascalCase` (No Spaces, all words capitalised).

```
private ModuleVariable as variant
public GlobalVariable as variant
```

Constants are written in `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE`

```
public const SOME_IMPORTANT_VALUE as string = "This Never Changes"
```

Function/Procedure Names are also written in `PascalCase`

```
Public Sub DoThisThing()
```

Event Procedures are written in `Pascal_Snake_Case`

```
Public Sub SomeObject_SomeEvent()
```

---

### Magic Variables

A magic number or magic string is a number/string that's set manually in multiple places and/or without context. E.g. `range("B1")` or `sheets("Sap Data")`. That string appears 11 times in your sub. If that worksheet name changes, you're going to have to change it in 11 places. Making it **much** more likely that you'll miss one, or mis-type one.

Whenever you're going to reference something more than once (and as a good habit, even when you're only going to reference it once), put it in a variable. You use `workbooks(main_book)` 28 times in your code. Instead, try this:

```
Dim wb_Main As Workbook
Set wb_Main = ActiveWorkbook

wb_Main.Worksheets(...
```

Now, if you need to change your workbook (or reference it by name, or some other change) you only need to change it in one place.

Do the same with your worksheets:

```
Dim ws_SapData As Worksheet
Set ws_SapData = wb_Main.Worksheets("Sap Data")
```

And now

```
With Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data")
```

becomes

```
With wb_Main.ws_SapData
```

And if the name of the worksheet changes, again, you only need to change it in one place, rather than 11.

The same applies to ranges. Rather than `Range("B1") = "assignment"`

```
Dim assignmentTitleCell as range
Set assignmentTitleCell = ws_SapData.range("B1")

assignmentTitleCell.Value = "assignment"
```

and then later...

```
assignmentTitlecell.Offset(1,0).Formula = "=Get_LongDescription(RC[1])"
...
```

Now, if you need to change the location of your assignment data, you only have to move the title cell and the rest of the column will move with it.

---

Good practice: Go through your code and wherever you see a hardcoded value ("1", "some text", "a name", "a formula", "2 to 20"). Think, "What does this value represent?" then replace it with a descriptive variable. `lastRow` is a great example.

In addition, rather than hardcode ranges to a specific row/column, hardcode your "Anchor Range" and then reference everything else relative to that. Rather than "This data is in column C", "this data is in [that data's column] + 1". You may find `Range.Row, Range.Column, Cells(row, column), Range.Offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)` particularly useful for this.

It may seem tedious, and look less "neat" but it reads **so** much easier than constantly thinking "wait, what's meant to be in column B?", "Why row 27?", "Why does this series of number start and end on these values?".

And, of course, "I need to move everything 3 columns over" or "I need to re-order my columns" becomes as simple as changing one letter/number, rather than manually rewriting every single cell reference.

There's plenty more but that's more than enough to be getting on with.

Comment: Thanks for comment and dtdate is nice catch. I forgot to remove it after altering the code. Now i removed it from my all modules. Also Option Explicit I never used and dont know much about it, Still learning.

Comment: after reading your full comment i got to know i need to much improvements. Also as i am not hardcore coder i took help from books,google and also stackoverflow, so might be i made code little complex then it is actually. i will work and update code again soon and reduce it to lowest possible.

Comment: @AtulVij You'll be fine. I've only been proramming for less than 6 months. I started by reading "Excel VBA for Dummies" cover to cover and then just writing stuff, going to SO until it worked, taking it to CR to have it reviewed, then repeating all over again. If you keep bringing stuff to Code Review, you'll improve faster than you thought you could :)

Comment: i have made code again from scratch but need little help can you provide code for inserting row in active sheet and total on basis of column B unique values

Answer (score 6):

First, you should give your variables names that are descriptive -

```
Option Explicit
Sub Previous_comments_and_modifications()
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Set MainWB = ActiveWorkbook

Dim SapDataWS As Worksheet
Set SapDataWS = MainWB.Worksheets("SAP Data")

Dim user As String
user = Environ("username")
'What is x? 
Dim x As Long
'What is ws and ds?
Dim MainWS As Worksheet
Dim UpdateWS As Worksheet

'This is looking for uniques, right?
Dim a As Range

'How can you tell which should be numbers or ranges?
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startrow As Integer
Dim endrow As Range
Dim updatesheet As String

'Some of these weren't defined
'b is the result of a msgbox, why not call it "msgResult"
Dim b As Variant

Dim Filename As Boolean

'What is c?
Dim c As Range
Dim dtDate As Date
```

Now you have a variable `SapDataWS` that is the sheet constantly written out, so replace every `Workbooks(main_book).Worksheets("Sap Data")` with `SapDataWS`.

You can also use MainWB for `Workbooks(main_book)`

After that, I'd use a couple different subs for each action you're taking. You don't (as far as I can tell) have any need for functions as nothing is *being returned* - but you could use a few sub-routines to break it apart.

Also, as I stated in the comments, try to avoid using `.Activate` - it's [not really needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

I assume you did a lot of this with the macro recorder - if so, great effort! But you can always optimize it.

You should also add some comments to describe not only what you're doing, but *how* it's doing it.

You have a lot of `With` blocks. I'm not a huge fan myself, but if you keep everything aligned, I guess it could work.

Speaking of alignment, I don't know how your code is aligned in the VBE, but what you posted here had no indentation - that makes it terribly difficult to read. It also means you ended up with an extra `end if` and `next ws` that didn't have an `if` or `for` matched to them.

You also have this -

```
Range("B2").Formula = "=Get_LongDescription(RC[1])"
```

Is that a UDF?

Your `.Autofill`s look good to me. You may have unnecessary arguments in your `.sort`s.

---

For me this -

```
'Its asking to copying comments from Previous Month File
Dim b As Variant
Dim Filename As Boolean
 b = MsgBox("Do you want to update comments for current postings from previous month?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Note:- If are runing this macro for the 1st time plese choose option 'No'", _
    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question")
If b = vbYes Then
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Please select previous month BL comment file to update comments.", , False)
    If Filename <> "False" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename, Format:=2
    End If
    updatesheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    For Each ws In MainWB.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sap Data" And ws.Name <> "Automated BL Import" Then
            For Each ds In Workbooks(updatesheet).Sheets
                If ds.Name = ws.Name Then
                    lastRow = MainWB.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    'Some formulas are insterted to reduce manual calculation
                        With MainWB.Worksheets(ws.Name)
                        .Range("T2:T" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-1]:R1048576C,2,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-1]:R1048576C,2,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("U2:U" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-2]:R1048576C,3,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-2]:R1048576C,3,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("V2:V" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-3]:R1048576C,4,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-3]:R1048576C,4,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("W2:W" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-4]:R1048576C,5,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-4]:R1048576C,5,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("X2:X" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-5]:R1048576C,6,0) = 0,"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'[" & updatesheet & "]" & ws.Name & "'!R2C[-5]:R1048576C,6,0)),"""")"
                        .Range("T2:X" & lastRow).Value = MainWB.Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("T2:X" & lastRow).Value
                        End With
                    GoTo next_ws
                End If
            Next ds
next_ws:
        End If
    Next ws
    Windows(updatesheet).Close
End If
```

is too much nesting. Looks to me like you just need to check for each WBMain sheet to match to `Workbook(updatesheet)` and then insert formulas. There has to be a better way to do this.

Do you need to insert all these formulas, every time? Shouldn't they just update as things change? If not, why use formulas when you could use values?

---

Now, as for how your question has been received with down-votes, I think that had a lot to do with the structure of your code and the lack of comments. Nobody wants to wade through a sea of code with no idea what is supposed to be happening or with having to look up variables as you run across them. Clean code is better. I'd suggest reworking it and making it pretty and editing your question. Then you may get more responses - I'm not the greatest VBA reviewer here, by far.

Comment: Yes i Have UDF buts its not working the way i want and i am working on it. Also what you recommended I like that and I will Make it Work that way.What i can remove in This and keep this code Simple and clean....

Comment: yes hat formulas need to be inserted everytime and i am not agretest coder thats why i asked review on it But som peple just voted negative without asjking any question.