# Excel Manipulation in Single Procedure part 2

Tags: vba, excel

So again I modified my last posted code as other fellow friends said me. So please review and let me know what more modifications and optimisation I can do in This code now.

Previous Post
[Spreadsheet Manipulations in Single Procedure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110941/spreadsheet-manipulations-in-single-procedure)

---

I have written VBA code to copy and do some formatting and create sheets based on unique reference and insert some information. I want to optimize this code and make it short as much I can. The code is broken into parts to help make clearer what I am doing with it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub new_comment()

'Coded by Vij, Atul (Contractor)'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ds As Worksheet
'Main Workbook Variable'
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Set MainWB = ActiveWorkbook
'Worksheet Sap Data Variable'
Dim SapDataWS As Worksheet
Set SapDataWS = MainWB.Worksheets("SAP Data")
'Worksheet Automated BL Import Variable'
Dim AutoBlImp As Worksheet
Set AutoBlImp = MainWB.Worksheets("Automated BL Import")
'Variable for Last Row Till which need to Copy Formulas'
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = SapDataWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Variable for New Sheets'
Dim LR As Long
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
'Screen Updating making to false'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Variable Q1 to U1 on Worksheet Sap Data'
Columns("Q:U").Delete
Dim CCGL As Range
Set CCGL = SapDataWS.Range("Q1")
CCGL.Value = "Unique Refrence"
Dim DaysNo As Range
Set DaysNo = SapDataWS.Range("R1")
DaysNo.Value = "No. of Days"
Dim AgeGroup As Range
Set AgeGroup = SapDataWS.Range("S1")
AgeGroup.Value = "Ageing Group"
Dim Poster As Range
Set Poster = SapDataWS.Range("T1")
Poster.Value = "Posting Done By"
Dim ClassT As Range
Set ClassT = SapDataWS.Range("U1")
ClassT.Value = "Class"
'Variable for Column B and Formula in Column B'
Dim stbFormulas(1 To 1) As Variant
Columns("B:B").ClearContents
Dim AssignmentGroup As Range
Set AssignmentGroup = SapDataWS.Range("B1")
AssignmentGroup.Value = "Assignment"
With SapDataWS
stbFormulas(1) = "=Get_LongDescription(RC[1])"
.Range("B2").Formula = stbFormulas
.Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
End With
'Variables for Formulas from Q to U'
Dim strFormulas(1 To 5) As Variant
With SapDataWS
strFormulas(1) = "=RC[-13]&""-""&RC[-11]"
strFormulas(2) = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)-N2"
strFormulas(3) = "=IF(RC[-1]<=30,""0 - 30 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=60,""31 - 60 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=90,""61 - 90 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=120,""91 - 120 Days"",""121+ Days""))))"
strFormulas(4) = "=IF((OR(G2=A2,G2=""WEB_ICWF"")),VLOOKUP(D2,'Automated BL Import'!$N:$Q,4,1),G2)"
strFormulas(5) = "=IF(RC[-6]<>"""", ""T"", """")"
.Range("Q2:U2").Formula = strFormulas
End With
'AutoFill Formulas in Column Q to U till Last Row'
Range("Q2:U2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:U" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
'Sorting on Basis of Column Q"
Columns("A:U").Sort Key1:=Range("Q2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
'Deleting Every Sheet leaving 2 Main Sheets'
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Automated BL Import" And ws.Name <> "Sap Data" Then ws.Delete
Next
'Coloring background as per format'
Range("A1:P1").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
Range("A2:P" & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 216, 216)
'Creating New Sheets on Basis of Unique in Column Q'
vcol = 17
LR = SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:U1"
titlerow = SapDataWS.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = SapDataWS.Columns.Count
SapDataWS.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To LR
On Error Resume Next
If SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol), SapDataWS.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SapDataWS.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
SapDataWS.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
SapDataWS.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
SapDataWS.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
SapDataWS.AutoFilterMode = False
SapDataWS.Range("Q:T").Delete
AutoBlImp.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Each post should "stand on it's own legs". Please add a description of what this code does, and a link back to the original code for context.

Comment: @RubberDuck part of code is having description like auto fill formula in column Q,etc. and original post i will mention sorry for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I think your new code has improved in some areas, from before, but it's also introduced all sorts of other problems.

### Readability

I haven't even got around to analysing **what** your code is doing yet, because I spent the last half hour going through and making it readable. If nobody can follow your code then nobody can use it. Give yourself a month or 2, come back to it and you won't have a clue what's going on either. Some suggestions:

**Indenting**

Indenting is one of the most important parts of readable code.

Take this:

```
'Creating New Sheets on Basis of Unique in Column Q'
vcol = 17
LR = SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:U1"
titlerow = SapDataWS.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = SapDataWS.Columns.Count
SapDataWS.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To LR
On Error Resume Next
If SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol), SapDataWS.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SapDataWS.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
SapDataWS.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
SapDataWS.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
SapDataWS.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
SapDataWS.AutoFilterMode = False
SapDataWS.Range("Q:T").Delete
AutoBlImp.Activate
```

I haven't got the faintest idea what's going on in there. Compare it to this:

```
        'Creating New Sheets on Basis of Unique in Column Q'

        vcol = 17
        LR = SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
        title = "A1:U1"
        titlerow = SapDataWS.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
        icol = SapDataWS.Columns.Count
        SapDataWS.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

        On Error Resume Next

        For i = 2 To LR
            If SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol), SapDataWS.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
                SapDataWS.Cells(SapDataWS.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = SapDataWS.Cells(i, vcol)
            End If
        Next i

        myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SapDataWS.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
        SapDataWS.Columns(icol).Clear

        For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
            SapDataWS.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""

            If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
                    Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
                Else
                    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            End If

            SapDataWS.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
        Next

        SapDataWS.AutoFilterMode = False
        SapDataWS.Range("Q:T").Delete
        AutoBlImp.Activate
```

Where I can immediatly pick out the features like `for` loops, `if then else` statements and the bits inbetween.

Off the top of my head: the indenting conventions I use for VBA are as follows:

`Sub ... End Sub` statements are not indented. **All** statements within a sub/function are indented at least 1 level:

```
Sub ExampleIndenting()

    dim var as variant

    do stuff

End Sub
```

`Dim` statements are only indented once. Everything else gets an extra level of indentation:

```
Sub ExampleSnippet()

    'Variables for Formulas from Q to U'
    Dim strFormulas(1 To 5) As Variant

        With SapDataWS
            strFormulas(1) = "=RC[-13]&""-""&RC[-11]"
            strFormulas(2) = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)-N2"
            strFormulas(3) = "=IF(RC[-1]<=30,""0 - 30 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=60,""31 - 60 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=90,""61 - 90 Days"",IF(RC[-1]<=120,""91 - 120 Days"",""121+ Days""))))"
            strFormulas(4) = "=IF((OR(G2=A2,G2=""WEB_ICWF"")),VLOOKUP(D2,'Automated BL Import'!$N:$Q,4,1),G2)"
            strFormulas(5) = "=IF(RC[-6]<>"""", ""T"", """")"
            .Range("Q2:U2").Formula = strFormulas
        End With

End Sub
```

And then various logical constructs get their own indentations:

```
For 
    For

        Stuff

    Next
Next

With
    Stuff
    More Stuff

    For
        Even more stuff
        If Stuff then
                Do This
            Else
                Do that
        End IF
    Next
End With
```

The point is to let somebody look at your code and immediately "See" what's going on at a structural level without having to wade through it line by line.

---

### Meaningful Variable Names

This is better than your original, but there are still **far** too many poorly named variables. `ds`,`AutoBlImp`, `LR`, `vcol`, `icol`, `myarr`. What the hell are those? I haven't got the faintest idea. I'm not going to write out the whole argument again, but to reiterate **Variables should sound like what they are**. If `CCGL` is a range then for gods sake call it `UniqueReferenceTitleCell`. `DaysNo`,`AgeGroup`,`Poster`,`ClassT`, all cell ranges containing titles. All with completely **unclear and ambiguous** names.

My advice to you, until you get more experienced with writing code, **don't abbreviate anything**. You're going to end up with long, verbose, names like `RangeForTitleOfThisDataSeries` that are going to make things look cluttered. But, they will be **clear and unambiguous** and that is **far** more important than using fewer characters.

I could go on but I'd just be repeating myself.

---

### Stop doing these things right now!

`On Error Resume Next`
Errors are **really, really** important. Thousands of people have spent **years** programming Error-Handling in to your computer, and into Excel, and into VBA so that things don't break. By putting that statement, your code is running **completely unprotected**. There **are** legitimate cases where it should be used, but they should be avoided wherever possible, and they should be **as short as possible**.

This is what a legitimate use looks like:

```
'/ Code
...

On Error Resume Next
    'Statement that might throw an error, and for which I've made sure throwing an error is an OK thing for it to do
On Error Goto 0 '/Restores normal error handling

'/ Code
...
```

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` you never restore that setting. While it's false **you can't do anything with your spreadsheets**. If you're going to turn it off, **immediately** go to the end of your sub and write `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before you forget.

```
For i = 2 to UBound(myarr)

    ...

Next
```

Your next should **always** reference the variable again. No exceptions.

---

I'm just going to point out that **a lot** of my suggestions from before also apply to your new version, so instead of writing it all out again, I'm just going to advise you to read the original again: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111770/81541

Comment: Thanks for comment again... What you said on previous post i thought and worked on it. The first code you mentioned is for creating new sheets which i got suggestion from stackoverflow fellows only. My previous code to create new sheets is very poorly written and creates error maximum times. and regarding strFormulas thing it is the easy way i found for providing formula. before it took  20+ lines to use formula and autofill now it takes 7 to 8.

Comment: ...... UniqueReferenceTitleCell. DaysNo,AgeGroup,Poster,ClassT  these all are categories or actual abbrivations like Class T, Poster is person posting the entry, Days no is No of days.,etc. and error resume etc is from previous codes only. I changed part of code and still working on it. I will update question again i have updated some more parts of code. Also taking some professional help to cut short the codes.